# Slice array of arbitrary dimension with lists of start and end indices

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to copy a part of a 3D array.
I have the indexes of start and end of the copy.

For example 2D array:

```
[[2 2 3 4 5]
 [2 3 3 4 5]
 [2 3 4 4 5]
 [2 3 4 5 5]
 [2 3 4 5 6]]
```

starting index, end index are:

```
mini = [2, 1]
maxi = [4, 3]
```

So the result should be:

```
  [[3 4 4]
   [3 4 5]]
```

I can write:

```
result = matrix[mini[0]:maxi[0], mini[1]:maxi[1]]
```

Is there a way to do it generally ? for 3Dim or NDim arrays ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your example... How do those indices give you that result? i.e. how are you indexing the "start" and the "end" exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is realizing what the indexing syntax is under the hood. This:

```
result = matrix[mini[0]:maxi[0], mini[1]:maxi[1]]
```

Is shorthand in python (not just numpy) for:

```
indices = slice(mini[0], maxi[0]), slice(mini[1], maxi[1])
result = matrix[indices]
```

So we just need to generate `indices` dynamically:

```
lower = [2, 1, ...]
upper = [4, 3, ...]

indices = tuple(np.s_[l:u] for l, u in zip(lower, upper))
result = matrix_nd[indices]
```

[`np.s_[a:b]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) is a shorthand for [`slice(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice). Here we build a tuple containing as many slices as you have values in `lower` and `upper`

Comment: Thank you. very helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `slice` object, see that example:

```
matrix = np.random.rand(4,5)
mini = [2, 1]
maxi = [4, 3]
slices=[slice(b,e) for b, e in zip(mini,maxi)]
print(slices)
print(matrix[slices])
print(matrix[mini[0]:maxi[0], mini[1]:maxi[1]])
```

Comment: Please, anything but the `range(len(...))`!

Comment: @Eric There, fixed.